# zf2 how to upload files, more than 1 file

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io, zend-framework2

I refer to http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/ and follow this, I can upload 1 file successfully by using rename filter in ZF2.

However when I use this way to upload 2 files, it goes wrong. I paste my code as following:

```
$this->add(array(
'name' => 'bigpicture',
'attributes' => array(
    'type' => 'file'
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Big Pic'
    )
));
$this->add(array(
'name' => 'smallpicture',
'attributes' => array(
    'type' => 'file'
    ),
'options' => array(
    'label' => 'Small Pic'
    )
));

<div class="row"><?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('smallpicture')) ?></div>
<div class="row"><?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('bigpicture')) ?></div>

$data = array_merge(
  $request->getPost()->toArray(),
  $request->getFiles()->toArray()
);

$form->setData($data);
if ($form->isValid()) {
  $product->exchangeArray($form->getData());
  $picid = $this->getProductTable()->saveProduct($product);
  $pathstr = $this->md5path($picid);
  $this->folder('public/images/product/'.$pathstr);
  //move_uploaded_file($data['smallpicture']['tmp_name'], 'public/images/product/'.$pathstr.'/'.$picid.'_small.jpg');
//move_uploaded_file($data['bigpicture']['tmp_name'], 'public/images/product/'.$pathstr.'/'.$picid.'_big.jpg');
$fileadaptersmall = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
$fileadaptersmall->addFilter('File\Rename',array(
    'source' => $data['smallpicture']['tmp_name'],
    'target' => 'public/images/product/'.$pathstr.'/'.$picid.'_small.jpg',
    'overwrite' => true
));

$fileadaptersmall->receive();
$fileadapterbig = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
$fileadapterbig->addFilter('File\Rename',array(
    'source' => $data['bigpicture']['tmp_name'],
    'target' => 'public/images/product/'.$pathstr.'/'.$picid.'_big.jpg',
    'overwrite' => true
));
$fileadapterbig->receive();
}
```

the above are form,view,action.
using this way, only the small picture uploaed successfully. the big picture goes wrong.
a warning flashed like the following:

> Warning:move_uploaded_file(C:\WINDOWS\TMP\small.jpg):failed to open stream:Invalid argument in
>   E:\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\zend\file\transfer\adapter\http.php
>   on line 173
>
> Warning:move_uploaded_file():Unable to move 'C:\WINDOWS\TMP\php76.tmp'
>   to 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\big.jpg' in
>   E:\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\zend\file\transfer\adapter\http.php
>   on line 173

Who can tell me how to upload more than 1 file in this way. you know, the rename filter way similar to above. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with a site i did. The solution was to do the renaming in the controller itself by getting all the images and then stepping through them.

```
if ($file->isUploaded()) {
            $pInfo = pathinfo($file->getFileName());
            $time = uniqid();
            $newName = $pName . '-' . $type . '-' . $time . '.' . $pInfo['extension'];
            $file->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => $newName));
            $file->receive();
        }
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Stephan Grobler! Sorry, I still don't know how to improve it. I add if ($fileadaptersmall->isUploaded()) and if ($fileadapterbig->isUploaded()) outside the $fileadatpersmall/big -> receive(); still, just the small picture uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and i managed to make it work using the below code;

```
$folder = 'YOUR DIR';        
$adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
$adapter->setDestination($folder);
foreach ($adapter->getFileInfo() as $info) {
     $originalFileName = $info['name'];
     if ($adapter->receive($originalFileName)) {          
         $newFilePath = $folder . '/' . $newFileName;
         $adapter->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => $newFilePath,
             'overwrite' => true));
     }
 }
```